# Extract zipFile from zipFile in memory

Tags: python, django

I've been looking for a topic like this in the internet and didn't find anything.

I have a zipfile that contains:

- zipfile:

  - index.txt
  - zipfile
  - zipfile
  - zipfile
  - ...

I'm trying to extract it in memory using the .open method, but I obtain ZipExtFile types of object. I need the extracted object to be ZipFile objects, is there any way I can extract directly the zipfiles objects to memory or transform the zipextfiles to zipfiles without losing any of its properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Say you have an outer zipfile `outer.zip`, which contains a zip file `inner.zip`

You can read the `inner.zip` into a `StringIO` object. This is a file like object, held in memory. You can then instantiate a new `ZipFile` instance using the `StringIO` object.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from StringIO import StringIO

outer = ZipFile('outer.zip', 'r')
s = StringIO()
s.write(outer.read('inner.zip'))
inner = ZipFile(s)
```

Now, `inner` is a `ZipFile` instance, and you can access its contents the same way that you did for outer.